# Report on Release Pipeline to a Work Item across multiple projects

Tags: azure-devops, continuous-delivery

I have a setup that requires the repo, CI and CD of the application to live in one Azure DevOps project. Some of the work that is being done on that application is managed at times in a different Azure DevOps project.
I know that I can allow linking and reporting on CD progress to related Work Items. My problem is that it seems to work only when the Work Item is within the same Azure DevOps project that the CD is in.
Does anyone know of a way to get it working across projects?
I have this enabled on the CD pipeline:
[image]

Also, when I navigate to the Work Item associated to this Release Pipeline I see this (different Azure DevOps project):

[image]

As you can see it does not seem to report on the progress of the associated Release Pipeline. But it does report on the repo that lives in the other Azure DevOps project. Also, if I click on the Release link, it will bring me to the Release of the project where work is being managed and not where the Release Pipeline actually lives.

Comment: Yes there is @Kevin. Sorry for the delay. I really appreciate your response and I have commented on it as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does anyone know of a way to get it working across projects?

Of course, this can be achieved, you can refer to the following steps：

Step1: Commit changes to the Repo with Work items.

**Note:** You can link the work item from another project.

To link work item with repo, there are two methods:

1. Use `#ID` in comment.
2. Select the work item ID.

[image]

Step2: Enable the option `Automatically link new work in this build` in `Build pipeline -> Options`

Step3: In Rlease Pipeline, you need to select the `Report deployment status to Work` and
`Report deployment status to Boards`

[image]

The Option `Report deployment status to Work` will show the release under the **link** tab.

[image]

The Option `Report deployment status to Boards` will show the release under the **Deployment** tab.

[image]

Based on my test, it could work on work items from another project too.

Comment: thanks for your reply. I followed your guideline to the letter, but still it won't show the Deployment when it's cross project. Not sure why I needed to check report to Board since I am just trying to get it reporting to the Work Item, but still I did that and nothing.

Comment: Hi @PaulKar. Could you please check if the release exists in the `Link` tab?